# How to create a dynamic regex in Python?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have a loop running which picks values of countries one by one from a list. For current iteration, say x_3 = "United Kingdom' . Now, I want to search x_3  in a text txt_to_srch keeping in mind that 'United Kingdom' can be 'United Kingdom'(more than one space) or '\nUnited Kingdom\n' in the text. The word 'United Kingdom is present in txt_to_srch  .

I have used the following code:

```
x_3 = '\s+'.join(x_3.split(" "))
x_3 = r"\b" + re.escape(x_3)+r"\b"
x2 = re.compile(x_3,re.IGNORECASE)
txt_to_srch = re.sub(r'\n',' ',txt_to_srch)
txt_to_srch = re.sub(r'\r',' ',txt_to_srch)
txt_to_srch = re.sub(r'\t',' ',txt_to_srch)
y = re.findall(x2,txt_to_srch)
```

However, I am getting y as empty list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `re.escape` that adds unwanted backslashes:

> re.escape(pattern)
>
> Escape special characters in pattern. This is
>   useful if you want to match an arbitrary literal string that may have
>   regular expression metacharacters in it.

Using re.escape on your first regex turns it into `United\\s\+Kingdom`, which will try to match a litteral `\` followed by an `s` between `United` and `Kingdom`.

Without it, your code works as expected:

```
import re

x_3 = "United Kingdom"

txt_to_srch = """Monty Pythons come from United Kingdom. They do.
United Kingdom is their home. Yes.
United Kingdom"""

x_3 = '\s+'.join(x_3.split(" "))
x_3 = r"\b" + x_3 +r"\b"
# print(x_3)
# \bUnited\s+Kingdom\bx2 = re.compile(x_3,re.IGNORECASE)
txt_to_srch = re.sub(r'\n',' ',txt_to_srch)
txt_to_srch = re.sub(r'\r',' ',txt_to_srch)
txt_to_srch = re.sub(r'\t',' ',txt_to_srch)
y = re.findall(x2,txt_to_srch)

print(y)
# ['United Kingdom', 'United Kingdom', 'United Kingdom']
```